# How to count 'many-side' entities from 2 tables one to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables related with 'one to many' relation in MySQL.
How can I select IDs from table one ('one-side') witch has exactly **N** related values in table two ('many-side').
I tried to use:

```
 SELECT target_id, COUNT(`target_id`) AS counter FROM `many_side_table` WHERE counter = N GROUP BY target_id; 

 SELECT target_id, COUNT(`target_id`) FROM `many_side_table` WHERE COUNT(`target_id`) = N GROUP BY target_id;
```

But it is wrong...

Comment: can you show your table structure

Comment: Try with having clause instead of where

Comment: Can you show some sample data?

Comment: Look at the answer given.. that's what I mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want the `having` clause:

```
SELECT target_id, COUNT(`target_id`)
FROM `many_side_table`
GROUP BY target_id
HAVING COUNT(`target_id`) = N;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT target_id 
FROM many_side_table
GROUP BY target_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = N
```